# Excel SQL query, append to the table

Tags: excelquery

Is there a way to do a SQL query in excel that appends to the table from the original query? I know there are methods using python that I can use, but can this be done directly done through Excel? Thanks in advance.

For instance, I'm interested in the data for the previous day but I'm having to add the rest of the data for the previous days to calculate rolling MTD and YTD. The dataset is large, and is only getting larger. With querying the data from the start of the year would take longer and longer each day, reducing the computation by appending the latest data to the original table.